# Как получить список каталогов на FTP сервере?

Tags: c++, ftp

Вопрос заключается в получении списка каталогов ftp сервера...
Пока мне ничего не удалось получить...

Отсылаю:

```
send(S,"LIST\r\n",strlen("LIST\r\n"),0);
```

Приходит

> 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /bin/ls.
>
> 226 Transfer complete. 8a232 bytes transferred. 8,04 KB/sec.

Что он мне прислал? (`Transfer complete ...`) Я ничего не получил... Как же можно получить этот список каталогов\файлов?

Comment: у FTP два рабочих порта - управляющий и для передачи данных. Вы шлете команды на управляющий, с него же читаете статус выполнения, а сами данные должны читать с порта передачи данных.

Comment: Т.е. нужно создать доп соединение... доп сокет, подключенный к новому порту? А где тут порт общения и принятия данных(p1, p2)? Я подключаюсь вообще к 21-у порту...

PORT. Команда назначает адрес и порт хоста, который будет использоваться как активный участник соединения по каналу передачи данных. Аргументами команды являются 32-битный IP адрес и 16-битный номер порта соединения. Эти значения разбиты на шесть 8-битных полей и представлены в десятичном виде: h1, h2, h3, h4, p1, p2, где hN - байты адреса (от старшего к младшему), а pN - байты порта (от старшего к младшему).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

21-й порт - управляющий порт сервера. Получение номер порта для данных зависит от того, в активном режиме работает клиент - в активном или в пассивном. Если после коннекта на 21-й порт сервера клиент решает работать в активном режиме, то он шлет серверу команду PORT, параметрами которой являются IP-адрес клиента и номер порта, на котором клиент будет ожидать подключения от сервера. Если клиент хочет работать в пассивном режиме, то он шлет команду PASV, в ответ на которую сервер шлет номер порта сервера, на который должен подключиться клиент для обмена данными. Т.е. при активном режиме второе соединение создает сервер, а при пассивном - клиент.

Comment: Понятно, а как получают этот список? в виде данных? У меня pasv соединение... Можете привести ссылку в сети  на нормальный пример на ftp+Winsock? Не понятно как получить данные по второму сокету... Они сами после запроса чтоли придут?)))